# Unable to store the list data into the Getx Storage

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am trying to save the list data into the GetX Storage i.e. coming from firestore in my application.

But somehow, It's not executing as expected. Every time I got the error saying: **Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DocumentData'**

> Below, List variable that I have created:

```
RxList<DocumentData> todoList = <DocumentData>[].obs;
```

> Below, My function where I am trying to write the values in GetX Storage.

```
//Function to get the all todos from firestore
getAllTodosFromFirestore() async {
   await todos.where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).get().then((value) {
    Get.find<TodoController>().todoList.value = value.docs.map((e) => DocumentData.fromJson(e.data() as Map<String,dynamic>)).toList();
    GetStoragePref.instance.writeValues('todos_list',Get.find<TodoController>().todoList);
  });
  return Get.find<TodoController>().todoList;
}
```

> Below, My DocumentData model class.

```
class DocumentData {
  DocumentData({
    required this.uid,
    required this.timer,
    required this.itemName,
    required this.isSelectedItem,
  });

  String uid;
  Timestamp timer;
  String itemName;
  bool isSelectedItem;

  factory DocumentData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DocumentData(
    uid: json["uid"],
    timer: json["timer"],
    itemName: json["itemName"],
    isSelectedItem: json["isSelectedItem"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "uid": uid,
    "timer": timer,
    "itemName": itemName,
    "isSelectedItem": isSelectedItem,
  };
}
```

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't store custom types (`DocumentData` in your case) directly on GetStorage. You can save the raw JSON (in your case it should be somewhere inside the `value.docs`) & when getting the data from GetStorage, parse the raw JSON to DocumentData again.

Comment: Yes, The same way I have done that later. But, I have one more problem previously with my model is that at the time of getting and setting data into the modal, the data should be in the form of it's primitive types only.  _From backend one of the value I got as Timestamp format that's why the above error is coming in the console_. Thanks for the reply!